# await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() always results in a failure in my ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently implementing the ability to login on my ASP.NET MVC project.  I am trying to use as much of the provided methods as I can.

Currently, I have set up a table in my database known as User, which stores all the usernames, passwords and other details regarding the users.

My LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

The AccountController (which is mostly the default, I have only changed the variables of the PasswordSignInAsync method)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.User.Username, model.User.Password, false , shouldLockout: false);
```

Why does this line always return a Failure?

It's my first time trying to add the Login ability, so any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

To method `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` in `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs`

Answer (score 28):

If username != email:

### It works for me:

comment out:

```
//var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

and add

```
ApplicationUser signedUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedUser.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your answer into a more legible way.

Comment: You should check that signedUser is not null. Otherwise that will throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve `User` based on `model.Email` and pass the entire User object as first parameter.

```
var user = dbContext.ApplicationUser.GetFirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);
```

The above query returns the userdata. Check if the user is null. Verify retrieved userdata and pass it as a parameter to `PasswordSignInAsync`. There are two different methods differed with parameter types.

```
PasswordSignInAsync(String, String, Boolean, Boolean)
```

Attempts to sign in the specified userName and password combination as an asynchronous operation.

```
PasswordSignInAsync(TUser, String, Boolean, Boolean)
```

Attempts to sign in the specified user and password combination as an asynchronous operation.

`PasswordSignInAsync(TUser, String, Boolean, Boolean)` performs similar operations as the above and succeeds the result. Below is the query to retrieve success result.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if succeeded.ToString() is == NotAllowed
2. If that is the case check Startup.cs for this line:
   services.AddDefaultIdentity(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
3. If that is the case you are trying to login with an unconfirmed email and you will be thrown out regardless of a correct username and password.
4. Confirm email or set RequireConfirmedAccount to false.